# Verification of proof on Bounded Variation.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, bounded-variation, interval-arithmetic

> Let $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function given by $f(x) =
>  \begin{cases} x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x}),  & \text{if $x\neq 0$ } \\ 0, &
>  \text{if $x=0$ } \end{cases}$then
>
> $(a)$ $f$ is of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$.
>
> $(b)$ $f'$ is of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$.
>
> $(c)$ $\vert f(x) \vert\le1 \forall x\in [-1,1]$ is of bounded
>   variation on $[-1,1]$.
>
> $(d)$ $\vert f(x) \vert\le3 \forall x\in [-1,1]$ is of bounded
>   variation on $[-1,1]$.

Solution:$f'(x)=2x\cos(\frac{1}{x})-\sin(\frac{1}{x})\implies \vert f'(x)\vert\le3$ on $[1,1]\implies f$ is of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$.So,option $(a),(b)$ are correct.

**Please check the following argument:**

Since, the only problem creator for $f'$ being of bounded variation is $0$. Now, if I take a partition of $[-1,1]$ which contains $0$ as one of its points, then the limit of $f'$ as $x$ approaches zero does not exist, but the variation remains bounded, hence $f'$ is of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$.

Please provide some argument which can discard option $c$

Comment: I don't understand what (c) and (d) are asking.

Comment: Are statements (c) and (d) perhaps asserting that *the truncation of the function* $|f(x)|$ at respectively at 1 and 3 is BV?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative $f'$ has unbounded variation on $[-1,1]$ and (b) is incorrect.

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take a partition $(0,x_1,,x_2 , \ldots, x_{2n-2}, 1)$ where $x_k = [(n - (k-1)/2)\pi]^{-1}$, and we have

$$V(f',[-1,1]) > \sum_{k=2}^{2n-2} |f'(x_k) - f'(x_{k-1}| = \\  \sum_{k=2}^{2n-2} \left|\frac{\cos \left(n- \frac{k-1}{2}\right)\pi}{\left(n- \frac{k-1}{2}\right)\pi} - \frac{\cos (n- \frac{k-2}{2})\pi}{\left(n- \frac{k-2}{2}\right)\pi} -\sin \left(n- \frac{k-1}{2}\right)\pi + \sin \left(n- \frac{k-2}{2}\right)\pi\right| \\ = 1 - \frac1{2\pi} + 1 + \frac1{2\pi} +1 - \frac1{3\pi} + 1 +\frac1{3\pi} + \ldots + 1 - \frac1{n\pi} + 1 + \frac1{n\pi}= 2(n-1)$$

Note also that $\displaystyle f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \cos(1/h) - 0}{h}= 0$ and your observation about the nature of $f'(x)$ as $x \to 0$ is not relevant in regards to  the total variation of $f'$.